# Compare current date with a date in d/mm/yyyy format in PHP

Tags: php, string, date, strtotime

What is the best way to check if a given date - a string d/mm/yyyy is a past?
When I used strtotime(), it didn't work well, because of non-American notation.
Of course I might deal with the dates as strings and compare substrings, but there has to be a better way.

```
if((strtotime('now')-strtotime($date)) > 86400) echo $date;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) manual

So a simple `str_replace('/', '-', $date)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

`strtotime('now')` is a hideous abuse of the function. You should just use `time()` to get the EXACT SAME result with none of the strtotime overhead.

```
$thatTime = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $date)->getTimestamp();
if (time() - $thatTime > 86400) echo $date;
```

relevant docs for [date_create_from_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Edited to include a `->getTimestamp()` call, without which this does not work (cannot subtract `DateTime` from `int`). Upvoters, please don't cast your votes blindly (I cast mine after editing).

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious answer would be to reformat the string like this:

```
$parts = explode('/',$dateStr);
if ((time() - strtotime("$parts[2]-$parts[1]-$parts[0]")) > 86400) {
  // do stuff
}
```

**EDIT**

However, Marc B's answer is better, so do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running >PHP5, this would do the trick:

```
function in_past($date) {
    $date = explode("/", $date);
    $now = time();
    $date = strtotime($date[1]."/".$date[0]."/".$date[2]);
    return $date < $now;
}
```

used like:

```
$old_date = "23/01/1985";
if (in_past($old_date))
    echo 'so last season';
else 
    echo 'future';
```