# Convert string to time in php, wordpress CMS

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a function  in WordPress to add data from an XML file to a MySQL database.
The problems happened after I got a date value from the XML. It's a string type and I format it to a datetime using this code:

```
$mysqlDay = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($day));
```

`$day` is a date value retrieved from the XML: "25/01/2013" (d/m/Y). And the value of `$mysqlDay` is "01/01/1970" (d/m/Y). Why does the variable `$mysqlDay` have value of the beginning day instead the `$day`? What should I do if I want to format it from string to date?

In a similar problem to the one above, if I want to convert a string formatted like "18:00" (H:M) to time, what should I do?

I used this code in WordPress to add these values to the database:

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_lps',
  array('date'=>$mysqlDay,
  'start'=> $mysqlStartTime, 
  'end'=> $mysqlEndTime),
  array('D/M/Y',
  'H:M',
  'H:M')
  );
```

Is this right? `wp_lps` is the table I created, `$mysqlStartTime` and `$mysqlEndTime` need to be formatted as H:M.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8387034/209139

Comment: **Question:** Why are you trying to convert a date **from** the format `d/m/Y` **to** the format `d/m/Y`?

Comment: cause the value which I got from XML is a string, and I must convert it to datetime type

Comment: Yes, you convert it to a datetime, and then immediately call the function `date()`, which turns it back into a string. Why?

Comment: I read it from google @@ Now, I knew that the value is not a string type, It is an object. I cast it to string. And now, I use strtotime($day), it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14522141/209139), I answered the question you actually asked. However, it turns out (after much discussion in comments), that this was the *wrong question*.

Here's the situation: you have some XML which contains a date in d/m/Y format. You can fetch that with SimpleXML. Now you have a SimpleXML object. Now you want to get that into the database.

1. Convert the object to a string:

   ```
   $date = (string)$date;
   ```
2. Convert the date into a format that MySQL recognises as a date.

   ```
   $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date)));
   ```
3. Insert the date into the database using the `$wpdb` library.

Your problem was in a couple of places:

1. The date was in a format which `strtotime()` didn't recognise, for reasons laid out in my other answer.
2. You seemed to be under the impression that you need to have a date object to save a date into the MySQL database. You don't. What you want is a string in a format that MySQL recognises as a date. All queries between your code and the database is happening in a language called SQL, which is entirely happening in strings. You may be using a library which abstracts that out for you (`$wpdb`), but it's still strings under the hood.
3. You seemed to think that `date()` and/or `strtotime()` returned date objects. They don't. The `date()` function returns a string. The `strtotime()` function returns an integer (which is a UNIX timestamp).
4. What you were trying to do was to take a date (a string) in the format d/m/Y, convert it into an integer representing a UNIX timestamp, turn that back into a string representing a date in the format d/m/Y, and then add that to the database. This was failing in two places:

   - The `strtotime()` function assumes that if a string has slashes in it, it's an American-style date.
   - MySQL doesn't actually like that date format either. It wants Y-m-d.

Comment: OK I saw. Thanks alot TRiG

Answer (score 3):

You can use DateTime instead:

```
$mysqlDay = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $day);
```

It is more elegant, and object oriented.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for you sharing. I tried it but it doesn't work. DateTime did not recognize in the system.

Comment: @JoeNguyen sorry for the delay, but which PHP version are you running? `DateTime` was added to PHP 5.2.0. Perhaps it would not be the time to upgrade your PHP?

Answer (score 0):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Says the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

So you want to convert those slashes to hyphens before calling `strtotime()`.

Comment: I got the problem. When I took out the value from XML file and set it to var $day, $day is an object. And that the reason why I couldn't convert it. I use var_dump() and get result "object(SimpleXMLElement)[1535] string '23/01/2013' (length=10)". With print_r(), I got SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 23/01/2013 ). Now, what should I do to get the value (23/01/2013)???

Comment: A cast to string should do it. `$str_day = (string)$day;'

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But now, when I use strtotime($str_day), I get the null value. Why?

Comment: For exactly the same reason as you did before: it's not in a format that `strtotime` recognises. BUT YOU DON'T NEED `strtotime`. It's a string. In the format you want it. Put it into the database. There's no need to call a function to convert it into a timestamp and then convert it back into a string in exactly the same format it's already in.

Comment: this is the code I use to add into database:
**$wpdb->insert('wp_lps',
  array('date'=>$mysqlDay,
  'start'=> $mysqlStartTime, 
  'end'=> $mysqlEndTime),
  array('D/M/Y',
  'H:M',
  'H:M')
  );**

Is it right???

Comment: In my database, "date" is a date, "start" and "end" are time. How could I add the value from php to mySql if they're string type? @@

Comment: What's with the random `@` signs in your comments? I'd suggest editing your question to add a bit more context, as it's harder to read when it's scattered all through the comments. I'm not familiar with `$wpdb`, so I don't know what that syntax is supposed to do.

Comment: That's the first way I tried. But it doesn't work. I decided to change my database from type date and time to string. I will format all in php and now the data which I add into database are all string type. I will format them in php when I need. It will be more simple than. ^^ The "@@" is my emotion. It means "I'm crazy now"

Comment: The database can be of type date and time. That's grand. As long as the string is in a format that MySQL understands as a time, it'll do grand. In that case, perhaps you do need to do a conversation: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date)));`